# Drifting issue in ROS2 using SLAM-Toolbox

Tags: slam, raspberry-pi, ros2

I'm slightly new to robotics and I'm trying to prototype using ROS2-Galactic, I am using built-in packages such as Slam Toolbox and others.
Now that I'm trying to run it, I'm having some issues with the created map as well in tf perhaps. I don't know how to point out where I am getting the problem, I am completely noob to debugging this stuff. the scenario is, I'm trying to do SLAM and I put the robot in-place without doing nothing, but it seems that the robot is rotating clockwise by its own as shown in rviz.
I hope someone is interested to help me, you can check clip here,
https://youtu.be/UVhMtrMc2ZU

Comment: A video of the SLAM session might be more helpful on a self-hosted website like youtube. I'm a bit weary of downloading arbitrary files from people I don't know :-)

Comment: thank you @StevenMacenski for the advise, please see the recording  here https://youtu.be/UVhMtrMc2ZU . I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry for mis-interpreting the link, my bad. It is probably worth keeping the link to the files in your answer, just in case someone wants to see them. The more information the better, and the more likely you are to get an accurate solution/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the fact that the robot's not moving, so I can't know if there are other TF issues, the most obvious problem I see is that you're not using a laser scanner. This is a 2D laser scanner SLAM method. It needs 2D laser scanner like angular data coverage. You're not going to get away with RGBD sensors unless you integrated 2-3 of them to get a reasonable angular band to scan match against.

If you have an RGBD sensor, there are specialized RGB-D SLAM's or visual SLAMs that exist that you should utilize. We're not in 2010 anymore where there aren't many or good options for RGBD cameras.

Comment: You are right!, although I am actually using a 2D laser scanner, turns out it is being interfered by the other sensor that uses structured light technology. thank you for your insight.